# @Scope("singleton") with thread Id in Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm working on a Spring Boot project with a thread executed by `TaskExecutor`. As far as I know, `@Scope("singleton")` means that if I want Spring to return the same bean instance, so if I declare it on a thread annotated with `@Component`, Spring will return that thread only. When I tried to execute that thread via TaskExecutor many times, I think it should return the same thread Id each time, but it seems to return different results. Can someone explain this for me ?

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyThread.class);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("Called from thread + " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
}
```

I have a service to execute the above thread:

```
@Service
public class AsynchronousService {

    @Autowired
    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void executeAsynchronously() {
        MyThread myThread = applicationContext.getBean(MyThread.class);
        taskExecutor.execute(myThread);
    }
```

My configuration file:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class ThreadConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(4);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(4);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("default_task_executor_thread");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
```

Then I have a controller:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

    @Autowired
    private AsynchronousService asynchronousService;

    @RequestMapping("/runTask")
    public String executeAsync() {
        asynchronousService.executeAsynchronously();
        return "OK";
    }
```

Here are the results:

```
2019-06-05 11:48:21.019  INFO 4056 --- : Called from thread + 97
2019-06-05 11:48:22.932  INFO 4056 --- : Called from thread + 101
2019-06-05 11:48:23.119  INFO 4056 --- : Called from thread + 65
2019-06-05 11:48:23.372  INFO 4056 --- : Called from thread + 93
2019-06-05 11:48:23.531  INFO 4056 --- : Called from thread + 97
2019-06-05 11:48:23.799  INFO 4056 --- : Called from thread + 101
2019-06-05 11:48:23.961  INFO 4056 --- : Called from thread + 65
```

Comment: I don't see what `Runnable` has to do with the thread it runs on. You simple execute the same task on multiple threads as you have requested.

Comment: Do you mean each time I call `taskExecutor.execute`, it creates a new instance of `MyThread` ?

Comment: Nope. It uses the same instance of your *`Runnable`*. A `Runnable` **is not** a `Thread` - the two are separate and entirely different. When you submit you `Runnable` (task) to the `TaskExecutor` then it either spawns a `Thread` to execute it or selects an idle `Thread` from the pool to do so, depending on the specific type of `TaskExcecutor` you have configured - from the output it looks like the former. If your `MyThread` was actually a `Thread` why would you need the `TaskExecutor` at all?

Comment: I've edited the question. Sorry I should have mentioned the configuration file. I want to create a thread pool to execute many asynchronous requests. Thanks a lot @BoristheSpider

Comment: Boris' comment still applies. If you want to create a thread pool, you have achieved what you want. What is your actual question?

Comment: Btw. `@Scope("singleton")` is a bit redundant annotation as `singleton` is the default bean scope. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context/src/main/java/org/springframework/context/annotation/Scope.java#L76

Comment: As an aside - if you're autowiring in an `ApplicationContext` you're doing it wrong. If you find yourself having to autowire an `ApplicationContext` you have a problem with your design that should be solved before going any further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope comment from @BoristheSpider had cleared your doubt regarding Thread and Runnable.
Regarding singleton, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56455668/2987755) will help you to understand more.
I will try to answer a statement from OP

> When I tried to execute that thread via TaskExecutor many times, I
>   think it should return the same thread Id each time, but it seems to
>   return different results. Can someone explain this for me?

It is like we are using different helpers to do some work, here helpers are Threads and work is your business logic (in MyThread).
Let say we will have only 1 helper to do our task and it will take around 10s of time and we need to do this work 3 times.
But since we have only 1 worker, it will take a min of 10+10+10=30s to complete its task.
In following test class I have added sleep of the 30s so that all child threads can complete its work before parent threads finish its execution.
MyThread.java from OP
Added some more logs and sleep.

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyThread.class);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("Called from thread + " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        LOGGER.info("Thread info+ " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        LOGGER.info("Thread info+ " + Thread.currentThread().getThreadGroup());
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

ThreadConfig.java

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableAsync;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

import java.util.concurrent.Executor;

@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class ThreadConfig {
    @Bean(name = "threadPoolTaskExecutor")
    public Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(1);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(1);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("default_task_executor_thread");
        executor.initialize();
        return executor;
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class DemoApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Autowired
    Executor threadPoolTaskExecutor;

    @Test
    public void test() throws InterruptedException {
        MyThread myThread = applicationContext.getBean(MyThread.class);
        if (threadPoolTaskExecutor != null) {
            threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(myThread);
            threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(myThread);
            threadPoolTaskExecutor.execute(myThread);
            Thread.sleep(30000);// 10000 + 10000 + 10000 ^^ for each thread
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
2019-06-05 12:31:01.549  INFO 68118 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Called from thread + 22
2019-06-05 12:31:01.549  INFO 68118 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ default_task_executor_thread1
2019-06-05 12:31:01.549  INFO 68118 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
2019-06-05 12:31:11.552  INFO 68118 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Called from thread + 22
2019-06-05 12:31:11.552  INFO 68118 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ default_task_executor_thread1
2019-06-05 12:31:11.552  INFO 68118 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
2019-06-05 12:31:21.554  INFO 68118 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Called from thread + 22
2019-06-05 12:31:21.555  INFO 68118 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ default_task_executor_thread1
2019-06-05 12:31:21.555  INFO 68118 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
```

If you check above configuration, since we have only 1 Thread to execute Runnable, same Thread is being used to execute all three calls.

If you change Total number of threads to two, at a time two threads will be used to execute Runnable(MyThread) and
once one of the tasks is complete another task will use the same thread which was free by earlier runnable.

```
executor.setCorePoolSize(2);
executor.setMaxPoolSize(2);
```

OUTPUT:

```
2019-06-05 12:39:26.163  INFO 68407 --- [xecutor_thread2] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Called from thread + 23
2019-06-05 12:39:26.163  INFO 68407 --- [xecutor_thread2] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ default_task_executor_thread2
2019-06-05 12:39:26.163  INFO 68407 --- [xecutor_thread2] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
2019-06-05 12:39:26.163  INFO 68407 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Called from thread + 22
2019-06-05 12:39:26.164  INFO 68407 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ default_task_executor_thread1
2019-06-05 12:39:26.164  INFO 68407 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
2019-06-05 12:39:36.169  INFO 68407 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Called from thread + 22
2019-06-05 12:39:36.169  INFO 68407 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ default_task_executor_thread1
2019-06-05 12:39:36.169  INFO 68407 --- [xecutor_thread1] com.example.controller.MyThread          : Thread info+ java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=main,maxpri=10]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept of singleton can be explained better that you've stated in the question:

There is an application context - a global map of all spring beans if you wish.

Now Singleton means that every time you request the bean (like you did by directly calling `applicationContext.getBean` or if spring itself does this for injection), the same instance of the object will be returned. It has nothing to do with different threads.

In other words, 
If you run many threads and ask application context to get a singleton bean, it will always return the same instance.

For prototype its different, always a new instance will be created.

So instead if this implementation:

```
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyThread.class);

   @Override
   public void run() {
      LOGGER.info("Called from thread + " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
   }
}
```

Try to do something like this for the check and you'll see what I'm talking about:

```
 public class MyThread2 implements Runnable {
    private Object random = //  createRandomLong // or UUID or whatever
    private static final Logger LOGGER = ...
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("Called the bean: " + random);      
    }        
 }
```

Now run it from different threads (and you'll see its the same instance)

Now in general Spring can perfectly work in multithreaded environments, for example Controllers can be invoked simultaneously by different clients (hence different threads, since its a thread per-request model).

Its not about the multithreading but about the injection.

Comment: "_since its a thread per-request model_" - yes and no. You would need to clarify that as "with Spring MVC running in a JavaEE servlet container".

Answer (score -3):

I write the answer how to create `Thread`,I mean you should look the source code about this line

`taskExecutor.execute(myThread);`

```
    Worker(Runnable firstTask) {
        setState(-1); // inhibit interrupts until runWorker
        this.firstTask = firstTask;
        this.thread = getThreadFactory().newThread(this);//**here newThread create a Thread to the Thread pool,**
    }
```

in your code   name "MyThread" it is just a `Runnable` ,the Spring hold only one that Bean, but it just provide an `run()`  method,
so  the **single** bean blow your code just a method. Does not mean that the thread in the thread pool is unique

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class MyThread implements Runnable {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyThread.class);

    @Override
    public void run() {
        LOGGER.info("Called from thread + " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }}
```

**This question is:**  *How to Create a Thread*

1. extend `Thread`

   ```
   public class NewThread1 extends Thread {
       private String name;
       public NewThread1(String name) {
           this.name=name;
       }
       public void run() {
           for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
               System.out.println(name + "running  :  " + i);
               try {
                   sleep((int) (Math.random() * 10));
               } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();

               }
           }
       }
   public static void main(String[] args){
       NewThread1 mTh1=new NewThread1("A");
       NewThread1 mTh2=new NewThread1("B");
       mTh1.start();
       mTh2.start();
     }
   }
   ```
2. Using `Runnable`, runnable is not a thread,it can be used by
   many thread.  my english is bad  i wish i can help you

   ```
   public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
   private String name;
   MyRunnable(String name){
       this.name=name;
   }
   public void run() {
       for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           System.out.println(name + "running  :  " + i);
           try {
               Thread.sleep((int) (Math.random() * 10));
           } catch (InterruptedException e) {
               e.printStackTrace();
           }
       }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
       System.out.println("main thread start running!");
       Thread thread1=new Thread(new MyRunnable("A"));
       thread1.start();
       thread1.join();
       System.out.println("main thread now is End My dear!");
   }
   ```

   }

**the below is Thread.class source code:**

```
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (target != null) {
            target.run();//the target is a runnable
        }
    }
```

3. In fact, There should be a third, and one is to implement the `Callable` *interface* and use it with `Future` and `thread pool`. it will return the result of each thread.   you can google it if you want to learn

Comment: My question is how Spring chooses a thread marked as a singleton component in the thread pool, not how to create a thread. Pls read carefully.

Comment: i mean you should look the source code  about this line  ```taskExecutor.execute(myThread);```

Comment: the Spring hold only one class ,but is is not means you have only one thread.   
 my english is bad  i wish i can help you